# time derivative of work energy theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, mathematical-physics, education

so I stumbled upon a step in my textbook which I can't do by myself, hopefully someone can help me :).

It goes as follows

$${\frac{d \bf{p}}{dt} \cdot \bf{u}} = \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{m \bf{u}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}}})\cdot \bf{u}$$
$$=\frac{m \bf{u}}{(1-\frac{u^2}{c^2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}\cdot \frac{d \bf{u}}{dt}$$

where $u$ is the velocity and $p$ the momentum as defined above.

My approach:
I used the quotient rule on p: $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{g(x) f(x)^{\prime}-f(x) g(x)^{\prime}}{|g(x)|^{2}}$
but my expression is far from the result given, so I think I'm missing something. If  you can help me it would be very helpful!

my expression:
$$\frac{m \dot{u} \sqrt{1-\frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}}+m u\left(\frac{u \dot{u}}{c^{2} \sqrt{1-\frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}}}\right)}{1-\frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}} \cdot u$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this even the work energy theorem?  first time I've seen like this

Comment: It is a part of a derivation to use the work energy theorem in relativity @Aplateofmomos

Comment: Can you show what you got? My first expression was $$\frac{m\dot{u}\sqrt{1 - \frac{u^2}{c^2}}  + mu\left(\frac{u\dot{u}}{c^2\sqrt{1 - \frac{u^2}{c^2}}}\right)}{1 - \frac{u^2}{c^2}} \cdot u$$ and it simplifies to the result shown

Comment: @StephenDonovan yes I've got the same result

Comment: but how does that simplifies to the last expression?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I went to sleep: multiply the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{1 - \frac{u^2}{c^2}},$ then cancel the positive and negative $\frac{m}{c^2} u^2 \dot{u}$ terms in the numerator.